# What are the fields of the ground reply (uplink) to a weight-and-balance request?

Tags: acars, data-link

I am trying to send from the Aircraft MCDU AOC menu (via ACARS Data Link) , a Weight/Balance Request downlink to the Ground Station .

I would like to know what are the **fields that make up the uplink message** to reply to this request ?